# jQuery: Can't retrieve an attribute of a dynamically created DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, dynamic

Here's the situation: I'm writing a simple AJAX application that performs CRUD functions. When the user double clicks on a particular element, the element changes into a text box so that they can edit inline. When the text box loses focus (code for which is below), the value of the textbox gets POSTed to a PHP script that updates the database.

All is groovy except for one thing. When I create a new record, which gets popped onto the top of the list with AJAX, I can't edit that record without refreshing the page. I mean, the edit *looks* like it's been committed, but when you refresh, it reverts back to the original. After refreshing, there are no issues.

**To boil it down:** When I try to run the following code on *newly created* rows in my table (both in the database and on the page), the edit appears to be made on the page, but never makes it to the database.

```
//Make changes on FOCUSOUT
    $('#editable').live('focusout', function(){
        var parentListItem = $(this).parents('li');
        var theText = $(this).val();
        var parentListItemID = parentListItem.parents('ul').attr('id');

        $(this).remove();
        parentListItem.html(theText);
        parentListItem.removeClass('beingEdited');

        $.post("databasefuncs.php?func=edit", { postedMessage: parentListItemID, fullTextContent: theText },
            function(result){
                if(result == 1) {
                    parentListItem.parents('ul').animate({ backgroundColor: 'blue' }, 500).animate({ backgroundColor: '#eeeeee' }, 500);
                } else {
                    alert(result);
                }

            });

    });
```

Comment: Maybe try this tool http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event to see if the focusout event is being bound to your new textbox.  Do they all have id #editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are not binding the event to the new DOM Element loaded via AJAX.

Comment: You can bind the event when the AJAX complete/success callback executes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the post executes but the function you target (func=edit) never fires, the params you are sending after the question mark are never read by your php, you are sending a post request and wanting it to behave like a get by attaching parameters to the URL, change your request to:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "databasefuncs.php",
 data: {func: "edit", postedMessage: parentListItemID, fullTextContent: theText},
 success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if(textStatus === "success") {
      parentListItem.parents('ul').animate({ backgroundColor: 'blue' }, 500).animate({ backgroundColor: '#eeeeee' }, 500);
    }
    else {
       alert(textStatus);
    }
 } 
});
```

Now in your PHP you have $_POST["func"] = "edit";

Hope this is clear and it helps. Cheers.